# Knockout select attr:{title Binding} not working as expected for Observable array

Tags: drop-down-menu, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I want show the **title(walk,run,talk)** based on select value when mouseOver on particular options.

[Here Is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naveenkumarm/Hc5vm/)

**Is this a bug in knockout (or) Am I doing Wrong?**

**HTML:-**

```
 <select data-bind="value: activityId,optionsValue: 'id', optionsText: 'name', options: activityArray,optionsCaption:'Select',attr: {title:'name'}">
```

**Script**

```
 // This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {

var self = this;

self.activityId = ko.observable("");
self.activityArray = ko.observableArray();
self.activityArray.push(new Activity(1,'walk'));
self.activityArray.push(new Activity(2,'run'));
self.activityArray.push(new Activity(3,'talk'));
}
function Activity(id,name){
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
};
// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

**Any help is appreciable**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have additional attributes on the generated `options` elements you cannot use the `options` binding you have to do it "manually" with `foreach`

```
<select data-bind="value: activityId">   
    <option>Select</option>
    <!-- ko foreach: activityArray -->
    <option data-bind="value: id, text: name, attr: {title: name}"></option>
    <!-- /ko -->
</select>
```

If you want to display the a `title` also for the currently selected element you will need a computed observable which calculates the title from the `activityId`:

```
self.selectedActivity = ko.computed(function () {        
    var selected = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.activityArray(), function (item) {
        return item.id == self.activityId()
    });
    if (selected)      
     return selected.name;        
});
```

Then you can use this `selectedActivity` on your select:

```
<select data-bind="value: activityId, attr: {title: selectedActivity}">
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/un2qh/).

Comment: It is working fine for the values in the drop down. How about the value which is selected already? When we mouse over it is not showing the selected value... Any way I like your answer but it doesn't solve my problem.. I am trying to solve this with title binding to a computed observable.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be this: http://jsfiddle.net/un2qh/3/

HTML:

```
<select data-bind="options: activityArray, optionsText: 'name', 
    value: selectedActivity, attr: {title: activityTitle}, 
    optionsCaption: 'Choose...', optionsAfterRender: setOptionTitle">
</select>
```

JS (main computed attribute for title):

```
self.activityTitle = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.selectedActivity() ? self.selectedActivity().name : "" ;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly the technique I was looking for.